# Will the official repositories update to Firefox 4.0 when it's released?

Tags: package-management, firefox

*Please do not mistake this for another post resembling installing Firefox 4.0 beta..I have no intention of that.*

What I meant to ask was in Febrary or possibly march Firefox 4.0 will be officially released. Would the official repositories update to the latest version or should I install add the mozilla daily ppa to do this?

I am very keen on installing the latest version of firefox 4.o when it releases. The firefox website only provides **.tar.bz2** files which means I need to compile from source. Hence the question if the official repository updates to firefox 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 will release with Firefox 4.0. However, other supported Ubuntu releases will remain with Firefox 3.6 in the medium term. When Firefox 3.6 approaches end-of-life, the other supported Ubuntu releases will be upgraded to the latest version of Firefox, although this may not be 4.0.

For those Ubuntu releases, we will provide semi-official packages of Firefox 4.0 in a PPA.

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-firefox-4-beta-and-rc)

Comment: Thank you very much..coming from a ubuntu developer maintaining the firefox and thunderbird

Comment: Is there already a semi-official PPA?

Answer (score 3):

It will be available with the upcoming Ubuntu 11.04.

Also in previous versions I think you will be able to use a PPA from launchpad.

Comment: I am sure it will be included in ubuntu 11.04 as ubuntu always includes  the latest stable version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall something about Ubuntu making a permanent exception to allow new firefox versions in the middle of upgrade cycles. If I'm remembering this correctly, then yes, it will be included, though there may be a delay from when the official Mozilla release happens.

Comment: I was thinking about this the other day. I remember hearing about this but couldn't remember if they said whether it was going to be during Maverick or not until Natty.

Comment: Oh that would be great if they introduce it official. In that way, it comes as an update automatically without the need for adding a PPA.

Comment: Could you confirm this answer, then I can mark it as the answer. thnx