# Is there a way to get a "proper" Firefox 4 experience on Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Firefox 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-firefox-4)

I'm getting fed up of Chrome's crazy memory usage and quirks and I'm tired of FF3's sluggish performance. I'd like to replace FF3 with FF4.

Now I've already installed it technically but the branding is completely off. It's using its codename. Is there a PPA of the latest *releases* (not nightlies) that comes with the proper branding and optionally a conflicts directive in its package so it clears out the old FF3 packages too.

Comment: I've been happier since abandoning ppa's for FF4, and going with the stock download from mozilla.org.