# how to install firefox 4 rc on ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

I removed the Firefox 3.6 from my system & installed it again using Ubuntu software center. But now it is showing the following error:

**Could not launch 'Firefox Web Browser'**

*Failed to execute child process "firefox" (No such file or directory)*

Now I am trying to install Firefox 4 RC but that is not getting installed too.