# How do I get firefox 4 on my Lucid Lynx ? I tried to install it using Synaptic Package Manager but can't find the latest version i.e. 4

Tags: installation, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Firefox 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-firefox-4)

Is the the packages still not out ?

Comment: Duplicate with  http://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-firefox-4

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate because the other question (now linked at the top of your post) does answer your question. We're trying to keep a lid on the explosion of Firefox 4 questions coming out this week.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Firefox is available for as a security updates in all supported releases of Ubuntu, just doing a normal update will pull it in.

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Usually it's available within a few hours of Mozilla's announcement, sometimes faster, depending on the archive builders, and the speed of your local mirror, etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer to accommodate the latest changes being the removal of stable firefox ppa.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the PPA `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable` for the latest firefox.

Go to System -> Administration -> Update Manager -> Settings (Button) -> Other Software (tab) -> Add and then paste ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable and Update.

Comment: This answer is now incorrect, that PPA is being retired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another PPA ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa for FF 4.0 (Minefield)

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa