# Why isn't Firefox 4 available as an update from the Update Manager?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

I have Ubuntu 10.10, and Firefox 3.6.16. When I install the available updates from the update manager, I don't get any updates for Firefox 4.

Is there a reason or am I missing something?