# how can I install firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: installation, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

I've seen Firefox 5 has been released. How can I install it for Ubuntu 11.04 without deleting my current Firefox 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to our own [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro):

> If you're on Ubuntu 11.04 you'll get Firefox 5 as an update within the next 24 hours (no need for PPA or any of that business)

(via https://twitter.com/#!/castrojo/status/83188233969737728)

The alternative would be to add the Mozilla Security PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
```

And upgrade your system. But again, it looks like you should not have to do anything.

Comment: by the way, it makes sense to wait for the real update. This will include things like translations and extensions to their full extend, the security ppa *might* not

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a fresh installation and not upgrade it, use the binary source (*tar.bz2*) don't install using the apt-get or synaptics because sometimes it will replace your previous firefox. *check the FTP bellow for the source of **Firefox 5.***

> [firefox ftp](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/5.0/)

*reference : http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-firefox-50-for-ubuntu.html*