# Does LTS releases include repo exceptions like Firefox?

Tags: official-repositories, lts

Will the LTS repo provide the latest and greatest of Firefox and any other softwares treated the same way? Or do the exceptions apply to regular releases only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All supported versions of Ubuntu now receive updated versions of Firefox as soon as they are released by Mozilla, there's no need for a PPA or anything like that:

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

No. LTS is about stability and not the latest and greatest software. That said, as soon as Firefox 3.6 reaches EoL, it will, most likely, be upgraded on all supported releases. The same principle applies to the regular releases, for example, Firefox 4.01 is EoL, and consequently got upgraded in Natty.

Edit: Firefox 9 is now available from the repositories for both Lucid and Maverick, in line with the earlier decision to migrate the users of those releases to the current version of Firefox.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/FirefoxRapidReleaseMigration

Comment: This is now incorrect.

Comment: ...and what is incorrect?

Comment: The latest upstream version of Firefox are now in the LTS release.

Comment: Yes, just what I said would happen, though I had expected it to become available later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable ubuntu-proposed updates, you will get the firefox 9.0.1 from there. No need for ppa repo. (I use lucid)

[image: My synaptic shows this]

Comment: Does this work for 10.04, the LTS? I remember reading somewhere that there wouldn't be any updates for 10.04 with Firefox.

Comment: I still have 10.04 LTS, and I noticed at the end of december, that after an update, I got firefox 9.0.1. I don't use any mozilla ppa. I'll update the answer.