# Are there any advantages to using the Firefox PPA over Firefox in the Repository?

Tags: 11.04, firefox

Is there any advantage to using "ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable" over just using what's available in the repositories for 11.04?

Comment: It's a newer version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages can take a bit of time before reaching repositories, having the ppa enables you to get the newest version earlier.
And that is it really.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no advantage to this as Firefox releases are pushed out to the distribution as quickly as possible after a Firefox release:

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

In fact, that PPA is [being retired](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=100).