# How to upgrade Firefox in ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

how to update firefox in ubuntu 10.04 LTS to firefox 7

Answer (score 0):

Or,you can download directly from Mozilla the last version and use from /home directory
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html