# Synchronize bookmarks between firefox and opera among many computers

Tags: firefox, sync, opera, bookmarks

Right now I'm using Xmarks to sync my firefox bookmarks among some computers I use (namely home and office).

Is there a way to sync these bookmarks between opera and firefox, so that I can use opera at home and firefox at the office, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already set up Xmarks, then actually the easiest way for constant syncing would be using the same [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) plugins on each browser and for [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/xmarks-mini/1.0/?display=en) witch takes care of showing Xmarks.

And if you take into consideration [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/), then you can see that it works for all browsers ([LastPass addon for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/lastpass/1.80.1/?display=en)).

#### Alternatives

[Delicious](http://delicious.com/) plugins or google bookmarks plugins on Opera and some other browser that has Xmarks so they sync from one to the other.

[Delicious](http://delicious.com/) can be imported also in [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) website.

Another way would be manually exporting bookmarks from Opera and forgetting about Opera.

If you have Firefox 7, then export bookmarks from Opera bookmarks manager, in Firefox 7 import to bookmarks manager and set up Sync in Edit->Preferences and register and save registration code in gmail draft or some other save place.
Now if other computers have Windows then preferences will be in Tools and there set up using Fireox 7 Sync on registration code received to apply.

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just keep your bookmarks in the cloud using something like Favsync so it's easier to access on any device.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer, it looks more like a comment.