# Why isn't Firefox 8.0 available as an update in the Update Manager?

Tags: firefox, update-manager

So recently I've read that Firefox 8.0 is out, thought of updating, opened the Update Manager, refreshed the sources, but there was no uodate. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: Sorry, the question is appropriate in this case since we usually push Firefox out shortly after upstream release.  In this case, there was an issue found upstream in 8.0 almost immediately after release.  Since this was discovered before I could complete my acceptance testing for 8.0, I decided to wait for 8.0.1.  Mozilla should be releasing 8.0.1 fairly soon and we will release shortly after them.

Comment: Firefox 8.0.1 is now available via the Update Manager.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firefox 8 had some issues with language packs and has finally been pushed out via an update:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/firefox/+bug/887339

Micah Gersten, one of the maintainers of Firefox in the distro adds:

> In this case, there was an issue found upstream in 8.0 almost immediately after release. Since this was discovered before I could complete my acceptance testing for 8.0, I decided to wait for 8.0.1. Mozilla should be releasing 8.0.1 fairly soon and we will release shortly after them.

Normally Firefox is kept up to date via the update manager (a delay like this is unusual):

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Answer (score 3):

This bug may also be relevant:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/888307

Answer (score 1):

actually, you can get the update through the separate repository... add this line into your terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

Then, run the update for the list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install // upgrade the firefox installation using this command..

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Tadaaa, Firefox 8.0 is ready on your machine~

[image: Firefox 8]

Usually, the Ubuntu main repo didn't update as fast as lightning for the firefox version, you need the external repository from the launchpad. I hope I'm solving the mystery~

Comment: -1 ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next is beta not stable, and ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable is for Lucid and Maverick only.

Comment: I'm forgot to add those infos~ I'm assuming that the one who asked this question is running the Oneiric, he should use the firefox-next but if not, he just need to use the firefox-stable... thanks for adding the infos @zpletan

Comment: Great answer :), @AizanFahri
But I think the OP wants the pkg from 'main' :)

Comment: There is no need to add 'plenty PPAs', in fact, if you use Oneiric or Natty, no PPAs are needed.