# Is Firefox 8 available for Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't Firefox 8.0 available as an update in the Update Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79186/why-isnt-firefox-8-0-available-as-an-update-in-the-update-manager)

Is Firefox 8 available for Ubuntu 11.10?
DO I have to change the PPA or something to get Firefox 8 for Ubuntu 11.10?

I still have Firefox 7 even though I updated (`sudo aptitude update`)

Thanks for answering my silly question.

Comment: sorry! I didn't see that duplicate! Ok Actually, Firefox 8 has an issue with language packs and the release maintainer of Firefox is waiting for 8.0.1, which would happen very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom repository for FF8, follow the instructions here for more info:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-firefox-8-on-ubuntu-using-ppa.html