# How can I update Firefox?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

I'm using [Ubuntu 11.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) (Oneiric Ocelot). How can I update Firefox? It's currently version 7.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or just refresh update manager.

It's part of the normal release system (v8 is in both `ubuntu-updates` and `ubuntu-security`) so you should get it. If you're still not getting it, there's likely a problem with your updates in general.

Running `sudo apt-get update` manually in a terminal should display any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Click the system/power cog and click "Software Up to Date" or "Updates Available" to bring up the Update Manager.

[image]

Click "Install Updates"
[image]