# Ubuntu upgrade of Firefox 9 in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

When or will Firefox 9 be updated in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

It has been in proposed for a few days now, so unless someone discovers any problems with it, you can expect it soon. I guess sometime during the week.

Comment: @BobBrazie Firefox is updated to version 9 now.