# Why does it take so much time for Ubuntu to update to a new version of Firefox

Tags: firefox, updates

From what I can remember, it always takes atleast more than a month for Ubuntu to update firefox. I know there might be some fixes to do with integration with Ubuntu, but won't this already be done in the beta face too.

And if I run the archive directly from Firefox site, it is pretty stable. Only the ubuntu integration is missing.

So just why? That's all.

Answer (score 15):

The official Firefox 9 release was 5 days before the Christmas break, so we took the decision to upload it to the proposed pockets over the Christmas holiday, to minimize the impact of any problems. It has now been published as a security update to all users this morning.

For Firefox 8, a late change in the beta cycle caused a bug where language packs were being disabled on upgrade. Unfortunately, we only caught this after the official release (but, fortunately, before publishing the update). This meant that the release had to be delayed for Ubuntu users.

The intention is that we will publish updates close to the upstream release date, and there really is no reason why we can't do that. The fact that we currently aren't doing this successfully, means that we just need to get much better. In the meantime, I can only offer you my apologies for having to wait.

- See [my blog](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=19) for more details on the work we do.
- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Comment: Assuming you are who I think you are: keep up the good work!!!!!!