# How to install firefox 14.0.1 from a tar.bz2 which is located in /usr/downloads?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I have downloaded firefox 14.0.1 as a tar.bz2 file. It is located in my downloads folder. Could you please tell me how can I install it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also, since what you want is to install the latest Firefox, this question may be of interest as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox

Comment: Why is `/usr/downloads` your downloads folder? Why not something like `/home/Sharma/Downloads`?

Comment: Isn't the same version available through Normal Ubuntu Updates.

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux If anyone wants to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

double click it and extract it using file-roller.

alternatively, in terminal:

```
bunzip2 firefox.tar.bz2
tar xf firefox.tar
```