# How to install Firefox 14.0.1 (or any other latest version) on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Here is the deal. My primary OS is Ubuntu 10.10. I like it so far and I don't want to upgrade yet to the latest version.

But, I also want to install the latest stable version of Firefox which is 14.0.1, as it is my favourite browser. What should I do as there are no more updates for Maverick through the official update manager?

I also have installed Opera through the latest version repository and whenever there is a new version I can update it. Isn't there something similar for Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the firefox [download](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?from=getfirefox) web page and install it directly.

- download the archive (`firefox-14.0.1.tar.bz2.crdownload`)
- unpack and run it:

  ```
  tar xjf firefox-14.0.1.tar.bz2.crdownload
  cd firefox/
  ./firefox
  ```

  alternatively, double click on the package and when it unpacks, double click on the firefox executable within.
- you can move the whole firefox directory wherever you want
- you can create a desktop shortcut, in 10.04 you just need to right-click on the desktop and select "create launcher". Point it to the "firefox" file in the newly unpacked "firefox/" directory.

P.S. As someone suggested, moving to a more recent stable release is a good idea. At least to 11.04. The LTS (long term support) releases get regular security updates and bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you said and now I have the v14.0.1 running. Nevertheless, the next time a new version comes out what should I do? Delete the folder which contains the 14.0.1 version and download/extract the latest one? Isn't there a way for this to be done automatically as in Opera?

Comment: If you have done as January suggested, this direct version of Firefox is can be updated independently of whatever the repos do or don't. Within Firefox, Alt+H and check for updates.

Comment: OK! But now there is a problem... NO YOUTUBE!!! Or as far as I can tell no plugins??? (PS: how do I make a paragraph, each time i press ENTER it posts the comment)

Comment: This is ..unexpected. I followed the instructions myself and installed the 14.0.1, run int from a directory, opened a youtube page and it just works (on a 10.04 system). What happens if you do `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`? P.S. comments here can only have one para and a few hundred characters.

Comment: Nonetheless, consider moving to 11.04. It won't be much different from 10.10.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted previous comment, as the problem persists. I accidentally opened the previous version of Firefox. In which directory did you extract the folder?

Comment: Result of "sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer" is "flashplugin-installer is already the newest version". Any suggestions?

Comment: From the link you gave me you can download the 32-bit version. But I have Ubuntu 64-bit and so are the plugins. When I installed Firefox 17-aplha 64-bit, everything worked. But, I don't like alphas that mush, so I'm going to wait for a stable 64-bit version of Firefox. Thanks! I wish there was something like Opera though...