# How to install the latest stable version of Thunderbird?

Tags: updates, thunderbird

how can I install Thunderbird 15 on Ubuntu 12.04?
I tried to install run the binary-file but I get this message:

```
./mozilla-xremote-client: error while loading shared libraries:
libplds4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I added `ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa`.

Comment: Thunderbird 15 will be released in the normal update channels in a few days time or so (like Firefox 15 was today), so there's no real need to use a ppa.