# Is running Latest Firefox on older versions of Ubuntu possible?

Tags: apt, firefox, synaptic

Is running Latest Firefox (ver. 16) on Ubuntu 8.04 possible?

If so, what do I need to do to accomplish this?

(If I can keep that latest support Firefox 3.6.17 alongside the latest Firefox 16, that's even better)

Comment: Do you know what is the last version of Firefox that work in Ubuntu 8.04? For example, I was able to run Firefox 12 but not Firefox 35. (since there are no more DEB packages, I am talking about the distributed official generic linux tar file)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But you need to uninstall the installed one first. Use `sudo apt-get remove firefox` to do it

1. Download the latest version of Firefox [from here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/fx/#desktop).
2. Extract it in a directory, preferably in a folder in your home directory.
3. You can run firefox by going to the extracted folder and double clicking on the "firefox" program.

   But you may want to have an icon like regular installation. Create an icon with the help of these questions:

   - [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)
   - [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/61218)
   - [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand?rq=1)
4. Now use the new Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It can be , but is not for sure .

Download the tar.bz2 compressed file from Firefox page : http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/ and **Save file**

Uncompress the file with (I assume you save the file in Downloads/ folder)

```
cd Downloads
```

`tar -xvjf firefox-16.0.1.tar.bz2`

Then move the folder with new firefox to /opt

```
sudo mv Downloads/firefox /opt/
```

connect to /opt and run the executable file

```
cd /opt/firefox/
./firefox
```