# How do I upgrade Firefox to 17.0.1

Tags: upgrade, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

I have just downloaded and installed the latest version of Ubuntu which is 12.10 (64 bit, US English).

The OS came with Mozilla Firefox 16.0.1

On Mozilla's official website, the version is 17.0.1

How do I upgrade the one installed on my computer to the latest 17.0.1?

Please provide detailed instructions as I am a newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried downloading for the official web-site?

Comment: I have the same ubuntu version and firefox 17.0.1. Have you tried using  Software Updater? I didn't installed it manually so it should be in the main repositories.

Comment: @Melon Please just use software from the repositories. It's packaged for your convenience and best compatibility.