# Installing Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04: configure no such file

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I have downloaded a tarball for installing Firefox. Once it’s unpacked, the `/configure` command does not work. I happened to notice that the unpacked folder contains configure, read me, or install files, but the error says

> configure no such file

What should I do?

Comment: Eeeh, `sudo apt-get install firefox`? Anyone?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `./configure`, with the dot before all?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with Firefox by default. If you’ve removed it and wish to reintall it, it’s available in the standard repositories. You can either use the point-and-click graphical interface of the Software Center or simply type

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

on the Terminal.

---

If you do wish to install Firefox (or any other program) from a tarball, you’ll need to be careful to enter *exactly* the commands you should. As Eduardo Cola said in a comment on your question, you probably want `./configure`, with an initial dot. The command `/configure` will try to run a script in the root directory called `configure`: no such script exists, hence your error message. The same command with an initial dot will run the script called `configure` in your *current* directory, which you say does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the version of firefox in the repositories

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

If for some reason you need a newer version, use a ppa

See [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

If you are trying to compile from source see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build and post the command(s) you ran and any error message.